# Why does characteristic of F matter in Maschke's Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading Dummit and Foote chapter 18 recently. I have a confusion about Maschke's Theorem.

Maschke's Theorem: Let $G$ be a finite group and let $F$ be a field whose characteristic does not divide $|G|$. If $V$ is any $FG$-module and $U$ is any submodule of $V$, then $V$ has a submodule $W$ such that $V=U\oplus W$.

The theorem makes sense but I am wondering why we must have the characteristic of $F$ not divide $|G|$? What if it does divide $|G|$?

Comment: Have you read the proof? The characteristic of a field makes a difference when you try to divide by an integer: for example, you can divide by $6$ in a field if and only if the characteristic of the field is neither $2$ nor $3$. With this in mind, try to spot where the proof would fail if the characteristic of $F$ does divide $\lvert G \rvert$!

Comment: That the proof fails only tells you about that particular proof, but read at the end of the section about the converse. Also mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem#Converse_statement).

Comment: Thanks so much for your hint! When we construct the $FG$-module projection $\pi$, we define $\pi=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}g\pi_0 g^{-1}$. If the characteristic divides $|G|$, then $\frac{1}{|G|}$ makes no sense.

Comment: Consider the representation $C_3\to \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb F_3)$ given by $1\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. It's irreducible, but indecomposable.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Is an irreducible representation by definition indecomposable? Do you mean the representation is reducible but indecomposable?

Comment: Sorry I meant reducible but indecomposable :)